# Define custom url's with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services

I want to set a custom url for my pages I am using angularJs. Like I have a page compare.html and one controller for it. My current url's are like "www.mywebsite.com/view/category/compare.html" I want like www.mywebsite.com/compare. How will I do it and I am using AWS.

Comment: Use `uiRouter` to route the url, define states and url with respect to templateUrl

Comment: I am new to angularjs can you please give a link for guide/ tutorial how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uiRouter` to define states in angularJs.

**Ex.**

```
angular.module("firstApp", [])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $state),{
    $stateProvider.state('compare', {
         url: '/compare',
         templateUrl: ' /compare.html',
         controller: 'MyFirstController'
    })
  });
```

go through some links may be it will help you:-
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: There is a # sign in URL like www.mysite.com/#/compare how to remove # sign.

Comment: # seperate your path, means when you change from one state to another state only the path from # will change, # comes after your context  path. So # is neccesary for routing.
but still if you want to give path directly then it is preferable to give from backend (JAVA or ....)

Comment: ok, but here i am facing an another problem the compare.html page is showing only in <div ui-view></div> I this page on full screen like a static page not linked with index page

Comment: yes you have to include this module name in app.js and have to include path in index page, for better understanding refer angular documentation

Comment: No that is working for me there is no error. I want to call another page which has different app & different controller totally independent page  from my index.html page. basically i don't want to change only the single view i want to change the whole page.